# Rails Action Cable: How to fetch User Agent & Client IP Address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am upgrading a Rails app to use websocket via Action Cable. For logging purposes, I need to get the client's IP address and the user agent who sends the socket message.

In the `speak` method of `MyChannel` class (`app/channels/my_channel.rb`), I cannot access the session or the request.

Do you have any idea on how I can get `user_agent` and the client IP address in this `speak` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get this info from request in Connection object to which Channel belongs.

Comment: Hi Xnust.. Can you please elaborate how I can access Connection object within Channel -> speak method?

Comment: Hi. In your Connection you can add f.e. attr_accessor :ip_addr, and in connect method set it's value (@ip_addr = request.remote_ip). In a Channel get this via self.connection.ip_addr

Answer (score 2):

To use the `remote_ip` helper you can do this in your Channel:

```
ActionDispatch::Request.new(connection.env).remote_ip
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActionCable::Connection::Base` contains all information about the current connection environment (HTTP headers, rack process, etc), and you can access it via its `env` attribute reader.

For example, here is how I get the **User-Agent** HTTP header which was used while establishing WebSocket connection:

```
user_agent = connection.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

Note that I run this code from `ApplicationCable::Channel` instance, where connection instance is available via `connection` attribute

I couldn't find any documentation about it, but I believe it's safe since `env` attribute is made publicly available (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.6/classes/ActionCable/Connection/Base.html#method-i-request). You can get the full list of the keys that this hash contains by running `connection.env.keys` in console (when `connection` instance is available, obviously).